# Arp Equation, simple, b = 0

Tags: calculus

I am working with Arp Equations. Letters slightly changed for simplicity/formatting purposes. 
\begin{equation}
q(t) = \frac{A}{(1+bDt)^{1/b}}
\end{equation}
now when $b = 0$,  how does the result end up being
\begin{equation}
q(t) = Ae^{-Dt}
\end{equation}
I thought it would be
\begin{equation}
q(t) = \frac{A}{(1+0)^{1/0}} = \text{undefined}
\end{equation}
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac 1 {kx}\right)^x = e^{1/k}$$

---

Adding more detail:

$$\lim_{b \to 0} (1+bDt)^{1/b}=\lim_{b \to 0}\left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{1/(bDt)}\right)^{1/(bDt)}\right)^{Dt}=e^{Dt}$$